# Есть ли выход из лабиринта?

Tags: python

Нужно узнать есть ли выход из лабиринта, вход всегда [0,0], выход [-1,-1].
'.' - дорога, 'W' - стена.
Я написал код, который основан на правиле левой руки и обозначении тупиков.
Код работает, но скорость выполнения слишком большая. Необходимо ускориться примерно на 30%.
Возможно ли как то оптимизировать if/elif/else? К примеру используя словарь.

```
import numpy


def path_finder(maze):  
    lab = numpy.array([list(x) for x in maze.split()])  
    checked = []  
    i = 0  
    j = 0  
    size = len(lab)  
    while i != (size - 1) or j != (size - 1):  
        if (i, j) not in checked:  
            checked.append(tuple((i, j)))  
        if j + 1 < size and lab[i][j + 1] == '.' and (i, j + 1) not in checked:  
            j += 1  
        elif i + 1 < size and lab[i + 1][j] == '.' and (i + 1, j) not in checked:  
            i += 1  
        elif j - 1 > -1 and lab[i][j - 1] == '.' and (i, j - 1) not in checked:  
            j -= 1  
        elif i - 1 > -1 and lab[i - 1][j] == '.' and (i - 1, j) not in checked:  
            i -= 1  
        else:  
            checked.pop()  
            lab[i][j] = 'W'  
            if not checked:  
                return False  
            else:  
                i, j = checked[-1]  

    return True  


print(path_finder("\n".join([  
    "..W",  
    ".WW",  
    "..."])))
```

Comment: `но скорость выполнения слишком большая. Необходимо ускориться примерно на 30%.` - не понял, может замедлить надо на 30%? :)

Comment: Вам лучше почитать по про алгоритмы поиска пути (поиск в глубину, поиск в ширину и A* - последний не опечатка, он и вправду называется "а со звзёдочкой"). Их сложнее реализовать, но они точно будут давать хороший результат. Сразу спойлер - A* и его вариация IDA* вам должны дать подходящий результат.

Comment: Нет, нужно именно ускорить выполнение кода)

Comment: вы бы лабиринт дали на котором протестировать можно было бы скорость - этот то все равно быстро проходится

Comment: Дело не в каком то конкретном примере. Это задача с codewars. Я пробовал разные способы ее решения, в том числе поиск в ширину. И пока что этот вариант самый быстрый (346 из 500 тестов). Все тесты должны быть пройдены за 12000мс

Comment: Поиск в ширину должен быть самым быстрым в этой задаче.

Comment: `checked` -> `checked_list`, `checked_set`. Обновляйте их синхронно. Во всех операторах `in` используйте `checked_set`.

Comment: Другой вариант: вместо `checked` меняйте точки на запятые вдоль пути. Так даже проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно попробовать так изменить код:

1. убрать `numpy` за ненадобностью
2. список кортежей заменить на список целых чисел (позиций в массиве)
3. в список не добавлять и не удалять из списка элементы, а сразу сделать список размером N*N и ходить по нему вправо влево

код:

```
def get_pos(i, j, width):
    return i + j * width

def path_finder(maze):
    lab = [[j for j in i] for i in maze.split('\n')]
    width = len(lab)

    checked = [0 for i in range(width * width)]
    pos = 0

    i, j = 0, 0
    width = len(lab)

    while i != (width - 1) or j != (width - 1):
        if get_pos(i, j, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            checked[pos] = get_pos(i, j, width)
            pos += 1

        if j + 1 < width and lab[i][j + 1] == '.' and get_pos(i, j + 1, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            j += 1
        elif i + 1 < width and lab[i + 1][j] == '.' and get_pos(i + 1, j, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            i += 1
        elif j - 1 > -1 and lab[i][j - 1] == '.' and get_pos(i, j - 1, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            j -= 1
        elif i - 1 > -1 and lab[i - 1][j] == '.' and get_pos(i - 1, j, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            i -= 1
        else:
            pos -= 1
            if pos == 0:
                return False

            lab[i][j] = 'W'
            coord = checked[pos - 1]
            i, j = coord % width, coord // width

    return True
```

**вариант 2:**

1. список `checked` теперь используется исключительно, чтобы получить последнее положение в массиве
2. в проверке на направление убрана вообще проверка на наличие в списке за ненадобностью
3. вместо этого в клетку помещается символ `'*'`, так что проверки на `'.'` уже становится достаточным и не нужно проверять что-то дополнительно

код:

```
def get_pos(i, j, width):
    return i + j * width

def path_finder(maze):
    lab = [[j for j in i] for i in maze.split('\n')]
    width = len(lab)

    checked = [0 for i in range(width * width)]
    pos = 0

    i, j = 0, 0
    width = len(lab)

    while i != (width - 1) or j != (width - 1):
        if get_pos(i, j, width) not in checked[:pos]:
            checked[pos] = get_pos(i, j, width)
            lab[i][j] = '*'
            pos += 1

        if j + 1 < width and lab[i][j + 1] == '.':
            j += 1
        elif i + 1 < width and lab[i + 1][j] == '.':
            i += 1
        elif j - 1 > -1 and lab[i][j - 1] == '.':
            j -= 1
        elif i - 1 > -1 and lab[i - 1][j] == '.':
            i -= 1
        else:
            pos -= 1
            if pos == 0:
                return False

            lab[i][j] = 'W'
            coord = checked[pos - 1]
            i, j = coord % width, coord // width

    return True
```

**вариант 3:**

по идее еще быстрее было бы решение, если и список `lab` сделать из двумерного списка одномерным и перемещаться уже в нем используя координаты как это сделано при работе со списком `checked`

Comment: @potisin, помогло? у меня просто не было данных на больших лабиринтах тестировать